# How to map xml file content to Java object

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, saxparser

I am working on project where there is need to map xml files to java based objects.

I googled and found JAXB is standard library used to map XML-Java and back to XML.

I am working on application where there are many datasource files in XML format are deployed. And I want to find out certain properties from this XML file at run time. One such example of XML file is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/FDMS_DemoDS" pool-name="FDMS_DemoDS">
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
      <driver>com.mysql</driver>
      <pool>
          <max-pool-size>60</max-pool-size>
      </pool>
      <security>
          <user-name>fduser</user-name>
          <password>fdms!</password>
      </security>
  </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Now I want to fetch **max-pool-size** and **connection-url** from above XML file using Java. I tried using JAXB but unfortuantely I am facing some issues.

Can anyone help me in mapping these XML to Java Object ?

Comment: You can use simple xml parsers like JAXP,STAX to fetch these values instead of using JAXB

Comment: @Sanjeev Thanks for quick response. I just dont want to retreive values but also needs to map it to Java object and use that object further.

Comment: JAXB is the way to go or you can also use xmlbeans if you wish. In both the cases you need to come up with a working example which can explain your problem. Currently your question is open ended.

Comment: `I tried using JAXB but unfortuantely I am facing some issues.` - What are the issues?

Comment: Issues like `unexpected element (uri:"http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema", local:"datasources"). Expected elements are <{}datasources>` are coming

Comment: Xpath eppears to be the best option for you

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way in your case is to download the `XSD` file and use `xjc` to generate the java classes for you.

1. Download http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd
2. Launch `xjc datasources_1_0.xsd`

More info about **xjc**, the **Binding Compiler** [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is read the xml files in Java, there are lot more options.
I personally prefer common digester. Its simple and easy to use.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/

Personally, I feel JAXB is a bit of overkill if all you need to do is read the file . Please note that digester cannot write the xml files back. Dont use it if you need to write back XML's.

Comment: I just want to read XML file and nothing else and map it to java file.

Comment: Digester is built for that. Please read through the documentation. It will allow you to map it to a file of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

xpath/jxpath is the most performant option for your case.