# parsing xml using reflection api in java

Tags: java, reflection, xml-parsing

This is my XML file.

```
<customer>
  <Field Number = '1' Value = '3'>
    <Name>customer1</Name>
    <Length>2</Length>
    <Type>regular</Type>
    <Method Number = '1'>pay through cash</Method>
    <Method Number = '2'>pay through card</Method>
  </Field>
  <Field Number = '2'>
    <Name>customer2</Name>
    <Length>2</Length>
    <Type>rare</Type>
  </Field>
  <Field Number = '3'>
    <Name>customer3</Name>
    <Length>4</Length>
    <Type>regular</Type>
  </Field>
</customer>
```

I should parse this file using any parser in java language.
But my java source code should not contain any component of xml file, for example
 `node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("Name").getNodeValue();` in the above instruction i've used "Name" but I'm not supposed to use it.
Which parser is efficient for this scenario.even code snippets are welcomed.
I must be able to parse this file on the fly and use the tag contents as class members and setter and getter methods.So i,ve used reflection api.

Comment: Please refer to one of my previous answers and see if it helps   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920624/how-to-map-xml-file-content-to-java-object/37920793#37920793

Comment: I looked into Digester XML parsing,but even in that there is dependancy of java code on the specific content of XML tags.

Comment: I need a java code that parses a XML file of standard structure irrespective of tag names and tag content @RishiGoel

Comment: Then I am not sure I understand the problem. Any XML should have a schema, without knowing the schema, how would you parse the xml? The tags have to be there, they could be optional. Would you want the class holding the parsed data to be generated dynamically? How and where do you intent to use this solution?

Comment: In the above XML file if i replace <Name> with <Names>,the parser code written in java must be able to parse it without any modification in the java source code.@RishiGoel

Comment: How would the program decide where to put it? What if someone mis-spells the tags ? Instead of name, someone can send firstName and LastName in 2 different tags? Point is, humans are smart enough to read and associate tags with certain fields, but computer would need logic to build it. If you can address all possible combinations, or some logic to identify what the tag means, you can write a custom program. Otherwise I doubt there is any way to solve this. You will need to read the tag from XML, and then decide where to map it.

Comment: Is this about using *parameters* or *configuration files*? Replacing string constants in you source code with variables is an easy task and does not depend on the parser you use.

Comment: This is about configuration files.I know replacing string constants with variables is a easy task but assigning the variables with appropriate values from XML file dynamically is what i need@Holger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the corresponding types already.
You may need to alter them slightly as without being specific (which you try to avoid) you will have hard time assigning xml elements with same name to fields(likely collections). For example you have to elements called 
So every element belongs to a collection should be handled as either a set (can contain any elements) or lists (can contain homogeneous elements)

```
<ExampleSet>
  <ExampleList>
    <ExampleType>example1</ExampleType>
    <ExampleType>example2</ExampleType>
  </ExampleList>
  <OtherExampleType>example3</OtherExampleType>
</ExampleSet>
```

You can now mark each type with a corresponding interface (XmlSet, XmlList, XmlType per say).
Now you can parse them knowing if they are a set they compose other types, if they are a list they are a collection of types or they simply a type. Now you can use reflection to assign the value or attribute of the XmlType to a String, int, long or whatever you need based based on the type of the field you determined via reflection.

A very abstracted idea below, let me know if you need more details:

```
void readXml(Xml xml) {
  if (xml instanceof XmlSet) readSet(xml);
  else if (xml instanceof XmlList) readList(xml);
  else if (xml instanceof XmlType) readType(xml);
}

void readSet(Xml xml) {
  /*here you loop through the elements of set and call readXml(child)*/
}

void readList(Xml xml) {
  /*here you loop through the elements of list and call readXml(child).*/
}

void readType(Xml xml) {
  /* Here you use reflection to populate the value of elements with the corresponding java types */
}
```